# dblink in postgres (dBeaver) certificate issue connecting to Microsoft Azure

Tags: postgresql, azure, ssl-certificate, dbeaver, dblink

I am trying to connect to my server hosted on Microsoft Azure from a different DB via dbLink. SSL is required so therefore I downloaded the certificate from the Microsoft Azure website and tried to do both - either put it in default directory or directly reference it in the dbLink Script, however I keep receiving following message

```
SELECT * FROM dblink( 'dbname=testDB port=5432 host=testHost user=testUser password=testpwd sslmode=verify-ca sslrootcert=C:/Users/Stefa/AppData/postgres/D-TRUST_Root_Class_3_CA_2_2009.crt', 'SELECT now()::TEXT;') AS t(a Text);
```

Detail: root certificate file does not exist

I use dBeaver on Windows.
Anyone had similar issues?

Thanks

Comment: "SSL is required"  by whom?

Comment: sslrootcert is being looked up by the machine where dblink is running, and as the OS user who is running the PostgreSQL server.  It is not looked up on your client machine as yourself (unless those happen to be the same thing).  So the dbeaver doesn't matter, and the "default directory" might not be the one you are expecting it to be.

Comment: oh yeah - that's right. Thanks jjanes